# Auto-Spell in C# Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c#, open-source, ocr, spell-checking, toolbox

Is there any open-source toolbox in C# Microsoft Visual Studio that  auto-spell words like Microsoft Word does? I'd use [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/), its good but it's not free.

I really need it in my OCR Application. Please help me.

Comment: Spell check on edit box or rich edit box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try SpellCheck Class in .NET

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck(v=vs.110).aspx

There are other attempts by hobbyist in codeproject you can take a look at it

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5277/NetSpell-Spell-Checker-for-NET

Comment: Thanks Haja but System.Windows.Control is not present in my references. What shall I do now?